# Einstein Notation Summing Order

Tags: index-notation

When summing an expression using Einstein notation we start with the leftmost index?

For example in that case of $$a^{i}_jb^j_kc^k_l$$

We start with $k$ or $$\sum_{j=1}^{\#}\sum_{k=1}^{\#}a^{i}_jb^j_kc^k_l=a^{i}_1b^1_1c^1_l+a^{i}_1b^1_2c^2_l+a^{i}_1b^1_3c^3_l...$$?

Comment: Addition is commutative, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which order you sum over $j$ and $k$ in.  Either way you get the same terms and addition is commutative.